# Can´t find python libraries when trying to run a script from a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to run a python script from a batch file but it does not manage to find my installed libraries, the error i get is following:

[image: error]

And my batch file code looks like this:

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\juliu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Users\juliu\Desktop\Evolo project\Website_scraper_system_2\blocket_scraper.py"
pause
```

I have checked similar posts on the community but does not quite understand the solution, can someone please provide a explanation to what is going on?

Comment: did you `pip install requests`?

Comment: Yes all my modules are installed, I can run the script with no problems from cmd

Comment: are your modules installed in a pipenv or in the main python lib?

Comment: It looks like they are installed in the Lib folder

Comment: when you go to `C:\Users\juliu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib` you can see the module requests?

Comment: Yes, i see a folder requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed the console command where python and changed the file location to that and it seems to work.